# IRCD configuration: authentication using a database table

Tags: linux, unix, configuration, irc

I set up an RCS server (hybrid ircd). I would like to secure it with authentication. But my user credentials are stored in a database table.

1- I cannot find anywhere documentation on how to configure the "auth" section of httpd.conf.

2- From what I understand I could use an authentication service (identd) but I don't understand how this works, how to set it up, and how to configure this to use a database table for credentials.

Please give me a hand with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using InspIRCd instead, I can use this SQL authentication module:
http://wiki.inspircd.org/Modules/1.2/sqlauth

Problem solved!